# Microsoft Teams Bot Send Images on Channel

Tags: office365, bots, channel, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to build a bot on Teams that would receive an image an give a certain reply.

I'm able work with the bot as intended on 1:1 chat, but on teams channel it does not recognizes the image as part of the message.

```
  protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        bool messageWithFileDownloadInfo = turnContext.Activity.Attachments?[0].ContentType == FileDownloadInfo.ContentType;
        if (messageWithFileDownloadInfo)
        {
            var file = turnContext.Activity.Attachments[0];
```

The content type when receiving an message from the channel is always just the plain/text.

Any ideias if it is supported passing images by reference in the channel? If so what I'm I doing wrong?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently file sharing with a bot is only supported in personal scope (1:1 chat) but not in channel and group chat.

Here is the [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-and-receive-files?tabs=dotnet#using-the-teams-bot-apis).

Comment: thanks, I missed the Note on the documentation page.